# XCTestCase for CoreData fails with "could not locate the entity for myappTests.Example"

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, xctest

Where I can create an entity like so inside an `XCTestCase` test just fine:

```
let entity = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(
                   forEntityName: String(describing: Example.self), 
                   into: inMemoryManagedObjectContext)
```

But if I do it like this:

```
let item = Example(context: inMemoryManagedObjectContext)
```

A test would fail with...

```
failed: caught "NSInvalidArgumentException", "An NSManagedObject of
class 'myappTests.Example' must have a valid NSEntityDescription."
```

How am I supposed to test Core Data objects if I can't create them the way it is usually done?

Comment: Are you adding your class files to test target? or Are you importing your MyAppTarget with @testable import MyAppTarget in your test class?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I import everything I need because I can create objects and use them just fine the old way with `NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject` or related functions.

Comment: there is a difference though, Can you just check if you Example class file is added to the app target or test target?

Comment: Yes it is. If not then my example won't compile

Comment: that is the issue, you should never add you class files to the test target, but rather import your app target as a module in your test class.

Comment: have a look at this blog https://www.natashatherobot.com/swift-2-xcode-7-unit-testing-access/ , since ios7 it is not recommended to add your class files to test target, make sure you remove all of them from test target.

Comment: We have plenty of CoreData tests in my project. I've just quickly check and both inserting methods works. There is nothing wrong with this code.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem too :) 
The problem, I guess, is that the entities are not known yet by CoreData. 
So, 
My Solution to be able to test it was to have an instance of NSPersistantContainer while testing.

```
var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer!
    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()
        guard let model = CoreDataUtilities.model(withName: "ModelName") else {
            return XCTFail("Model should load")
        }
        storeFolder = FileManager.default.temporaryDirectory.appendingPathComponent("storeDirectory", isDirectory: true)
        let storeURL = storeFolder.appendingPathComponent("store.db")
        let storeInfo = NSPersistentStoreDescription(url: storeURL)
        storeInfo.type = NSSQLiteStoreType
        persistentContainer = NSPersistentContainer(name: "ModelName", managedObjectModel: model)
        persistentContainer.persistentStoreDescriptions = [storeInfo]
        return
    }
```

Now you can use CoreData the classic way.

Comment: Nope, entities are very well known to CoreData because I can create them with `NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject`

Comment: If entities were known by CoreData you would not get this error, give it a try.

Comment: I don't think you code is wrong, but that's not what I was asking for